# I want to simulate/mimic an "external API" which will send certain responses to my Django project?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I am creating a web application for *data visualizations and analytics*. I am using **Django** for that purpose.

Now the problem is that, in normal circumstances, this project will take its data (for visualizations purposes) from an **external API** owned by someone else. And for me to access that API I need to prove my identity and go through many formalities.

To avoid this *time-gap*, I want an app to **mimic** those external APIs. Basically I want to tell the mimic to throw certain **Responses** on certain **API endpoints**. I heard that **"Postman"** is good for the purpose but don't have any idea even if it will help me. I'm also open to any alternatives, if any.

P.S. I'm new to all this web-app stuff so I have no idea If my question is valid.

> Im working on Windows 10 platform

> Also this is an educational project by the way. It is not meant for
> any profit.

Comment: If you know the schema of what you're trying to mimic, there are apps like mocki or mockapi that's suited for this.

Comment: Thanks that should work